# GPU showing up in additional drivers but not nvidia-smi or lshw

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

According to Software and Updates, both of my GPUs seem to have their drivers enabled:

[image: additional_drivers]

I see them with `lspci` as well:

```
$ lspci | grep K80
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev ff)
05:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev ff)
```

However the K80 driver doesn't show up with `lshw`:

```
$ lshw -C video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK110 [GeForce GTX 780]
```

or `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.26       Driver Version: 440.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 26%   25C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    649MiB /  3014MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

The 780 works fine for gaming but I can't use the K80.
Any help is appreciated.